# How to decide what's private and what's public in an ADT?

Tags: c++

I'm just beginning to learn about ADTs in C++, and I was wondering if there was a general rule for deciding whether a method or variable should be public or private.  What does it mean for a method to expose "concrete details about the representation" that makes it inappropriate to include as a public member?

Comment: This seems to be more of a theoretical question (beauty of O-O principles and all that).  SO is for practical coding issues.  This might be better on either programmers or cstheory.

Comment: About C#, but still seems to apply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789322/how-to-decide-if-a-method-will-be-private-protected-internal-or-public-c?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADTs should not have any member variables, and because private member functions are part of the implementation, they should not have any of those either.

An ADT is a description of an interface. The interface of a class is (generally) a set of public member functions, which the outside world uses to interact with the underlying object. The phrase "concrete details about the representation" refers to information about how something is represented. For example, in C++, `vector`s are stored internally as dynamically allocated arrays. This fact is not important to their use as dynamic lists. Therefore, it is not included in the interface.